# how to configure xmrig cpu percentage?

Tags: cpu, rdp, mining

I'm confused and don't know what to do, i visited lot of wbesites and forums, asking how i can configure xmrig miner, i have rdp with 32 core 128gb ram, when i try to use xmring miner in it , cpu will work only by 32%, i want someone to help me to increase max cpu usage in the miner, i want to make it 75%, i will pleasure lot if you help
I need to edit config.json in the miner but when i did it , i didn't see any modification :( ,
and also when i use the miner in rdp with 4 core the miner will work 100% from cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/issues/1139) on github:

> You can change threads count in cpu object https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/blob/master/doc/CPU.md
> Main reason why this option removed is most of users don't ever understand how this option works (or not works), but likely this option will come back with new less confusing name, together with OpenCL backend.
> Thank you.

So you can amp the threads up instead of CPU usage, as more threads = more CPU usage

Note: Is this connected to the previous (deleted) question? Where your RDP was stolen?

Comment: Thanks Leo, its really worked from that link :)